# Using $_GET for multiple links in one php code

Tags: php, get, hyperlink

Php newb here. I have a registration form that when you have errors in registering, it just redirects back to the form, not telling what the error is. So I'm wanting to make an error.php, and make it, instead of redirecting to the registration page, redirect to the error.php?error=whatever.. Thing is, I'm not sure how to use the $_GET methods and whatnot. Any help?

Comment: Assuming the `$_GET` is being set, they are just like arrays. You can access a `$_GET` variable like this: `$_GET['key']` where key is the parameter name in the URL e.g. `?key=Hello+World`

Answer (score 0):

**On redirection**

The best way to do this is IMO is to [send the form data via AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your PHP file, then have your PHP file respond with a yes/no on if the data is valid or not. Once the AJAX return says your data is valid, then proceed to the registration page (or wherever you're going).

This avoids the need for the user to go back and forth just to figure out what form data they did wrong.

**On $_GET**

See the [`$_GET` section of the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). You can access `$_GET` as an array, or get specific values from it.

This PHP...

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['example'];
?>
```

...would retrieve and echo the value of the following text box.

```
<form method="get" action="targetFile.php">
    <input name="example" type="text" />
</form>
```

Also, make sure you're running this on a server of some kind, even if it's local. A web browser alone cannot process PHP and thus will give you the "white page of doom." I use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

I know some people hate W3schools, but if you're still struggling check out [this guide](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp).